# Java SQL SELECT query using PrepareStatment

Tags: java, sql

This is a simple SELECT query from a database using the `PrepareStatement`, but query returns no results. I tried without it also and not working.

```
try {
    // Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/pavillons","saiid","saiid");
    Query =" SELECT NOM_PRENOM FROM SAIID.ETUDIANT_PAV WHERE PAVILLONS = ? AND CHAMBRE = ? " ;
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, pav);
    ps.setString(2, ch); 

    reslt = ps.executeQuery();
    afuf= reslt.getString("NOM_PRENOM");
    System.out.println ("dooooooooo"+afuf);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query Executed");
    return reslt;       
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    return reslt;
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: i get no result for my auery

Answer (score 2):

The `ResultSet` starts before the first row ([`ResultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) notes *A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on*). Add a call to `rs.next()`

```
if (reslt.next()) {
    afuf= reslt.getString("NOM_PRENOM");
}
```

Comment: thanks i accounter this problem before and i fixed, this is portion of a function i use in another function where i do the reslt.next() and still the same thing no result

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
  {  
      ResultSet Rst = null;
      String selctedItemPAV = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
      String selctedItemCH = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
      final String Query =" SELECT NOM_PRENOM FROM SAIID.ETUDIANT_PAV WHERE PAVILLONS = ? AND CHAMBRE = ? " ;
      Rst = theSelectQuery(Query,selctedItemPAV ,selctedItemCH);
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        jList3.setModel(listModel);
        System.out.println ("doppppppppp");
        listModel.clear();
         System.out.println ("doppppppppp222222222");
     while (Rst.next()) 
     {
          String aff="hhh";
          aff= Rst.getString("NOM_PRENOM");
          System.out.println ("dooooooooo"+aff);
         listModel.addElement(aff);
      }
  }
  catch (Exception ex){
  }
public ResultSet theSelectQuery (String query , String pav, String ch) throws SQLException
{
    Connection con= null;
    Statement st= null;
    ResultSet reslt =null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try 
    {
        //Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/pavillons","saiid","saiid");
        //st =  con.createStatement();
        //reslt = st.executeQuery(query);
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, pav);
        ps.setString(2, ch); 
        String afuf="hhh";
        reslt = ps.executeQuery();
        afuf= reslt.getString("NOM_PRENOM");
        //if (reslt == null) System.out.println(query);
        System.out.println ("dooooooooo"+afuf);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query Executed");
        return reslt;

    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    return reslt;
    }

}
```